# Resizeable Rectangle Overlay in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interaction

I am trying to make an Application in which a user Click an image.
After clicking image there should come 3 rectangles which can be moved and resized according to the text in image.

So My question is How to make those 3 rectangles over a view to select text from portion of Image

Please Help me to make the solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly what you want, but this example shows how do draw a single rectangle over `ImageView` and scale/move it:

```
public class OverlayImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    private Rect mInitialRect;
    private Paint mDrawPaint;

    public OverlayImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public OverlayImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public OverlayImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

        mDrawPaint = new Paint();
        mDrawPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mDrawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mDrawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mInitialRect = new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    invalidate();
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.drawRect(mInitialRect, mDrawPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made the rectangle but i want three rectangles which are focusable when i tried to add these rectangle one is focusable and other two are not functioning. Help , How to add two more resizeable rectangle.

Comment: @Corrupt you can store array of rectangles and detect inside onTouchEvent which one is located a MotionEvent. And inside onDraw method draw each rectangle with scaling.